# How does one ascertain what the components of RFC 3615's examples represent?

Tags: rfc, banking, onlinebanking

The `SWIFT` URN namespace declaration RFC (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3615/) provides

1. `urn:swift:xsd:epp$mi.i-2.0` and
2. `urn:swift:type:fin$103`

as examples, yet does not explain what the short phrases

1. > `xsd`
2. > `epp`
3. > `mi.i-2.0`
4. > `type` and
5. > `fin$103`

specifically represent, in contrast to all alternative RFCs I've had the previous pleasure of reading. Although it is mentioned that

> the URNs in this namespace are opaque

I've no knowledge either of what this means, and have been unable to locate any standardized terminology referencing this term, so I don't know whether the information I desire is deliberately unavailable, or even unavailable.

Is there any feasible way for me to ascertain how to accurately create an RFC 3615 compliant URN other than guessing? Thus far I have estimated that `xsd` and `type` probably refer to BICs, and their successor `epp` and `mi.*`s refer to IBANs, but this doesn't appear correct based upon the more complex examples provided by the RFC.

Thanks for any responses.